# Python Numpy : operands could not be broadcast together with shapes

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, mean-square-error

I am getting this error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes"  for this code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
beantown = load_boston()
x=beantown.data
y=beantown.target
model = LinearRegression()
model = model.fit(x,y)

def mse(truth, predictions): 
    return ((truth - predictions) ** 2).mean(None)
print model.score(x,y)
print mse(x,y)
```

The error is on the line  print mse(x,y)

Error is ValueError:

```
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (506,13) (506,)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reshape `y`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
beantown = load_boston()
x = beantown.data
y = beantown.target
y = y.reshape(y.size, 1)
model = LinearRegression()
model = model.fit(x, y)


def mse(truth, predictions):
    return ((truth - predictions) ** 2).mean(None)
print model.score(x, y)
print mse(x, y)
```

Comment: great it works! But I am trying both the model.score and the mse should return the same value, which is not happening .

Comment: Yes, it is probably a good idea to check the definition of score [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.score).